# index match a number from other tables and if not found then match first 3 digits

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 tables where data is stored. I have 4th result table where i am pulling the minimum of 3 depending on the ref-ID i am using. Please see pic below:

[image]

4th table pic:

[image]

This is the code i am using on elec-rate column -

`=MIN(IFERROR(INDEX($E$2:$G$50,MATCH($A3,$E$2:$E$50,0),3),100),IFERROR(INDEX($I$2:$K$50,MATCH($A3,$I$2:$I$50,0),3),100),IFERROR(INDEX($M$2:$O$50,MATCH($A3,$M$2:$M$50,0),3),100))`

my question is for the ref-ID 2990011/2990012, since its returning 100 it means the ref-id doesnt exist in other table so it should take the first 3 digits of refid and match exactly with 3 digits of other tables and return the minimum value. How am i able to do that ? Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: The formula you describe would look like IF(**[Your formula]** returns a result then show **[Your formula]**'s result Else execute **[another formula]**. That means that the new formula will be at least 3 times as big as the one you have. I think that monster isn't manageable and recommend you switch to VBA, perhaps a UDF.

Comment: @Variatus ok thank you. i will look into the vba udf. the formula i am using , can that be shortened somehow ? because right now i have it in lots of files. and you are right, my formulas are bigger than this in some places :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is an introduction to UDFs. Please bear with me if the function doesn't do exactly what you want. In fact, I wouldn't mind because the objective isn't as much to provide a solution as to provide an introduction. First, here is a code dump. Install it all in a standard code module of your workbook. That is a module which doesn't previously exist. You need to create it and its name will be `Module1`. You can rename it.

The code will do nothing by its mere presence. Save your workbook in XLSM format.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub TestUdf()
    ' 020
Dim Criteria As Range
Dim FirstTblID As Integer
Dim NumTables As Integer

Set Criteria = Range("A20")
FirstTblID = 1
NumTables = 3
Debug.Print Lowest(Criteria, FirstTblID, NumTables)

End Sub

Function Lowest(Criteria As Range, _
                FirstTblID As Integer, _
                NumTables As Integer) As Double
    ' 020

    Dim Fun As Double                   ' function return value
    Dim Crit As String                  ' value of the received range "Criteria"
    Dim SearchRng As Range              ' range to search in
    Dim Fnd As Range                    ' Cell where match was found
    Dim LookUp As Double                ' individual lookup value
    Dim i As Integer                    ' loop counter

    Crit = Criteria.Value
    For i = FirstTblID To (FirstTblID + NumTables - 1)
        Set SearchRng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table" & i).DataBodyRange.Columns(1)
        Set Fnd = SearchRng.Find(What:=Crit, _
                                 After:=SearchRng.Cells(SearchRng.Cells.Count), _
                                 LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                 LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                 SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                 MatchCase:=False)
        If Fnd Is Nothing Then
            ' if the Find wasn't successful
            LookUp = FindAverage(Crit, SearchRng)
        Else
            LookUp = Fnd.Offset(0, 2).Value
        End If
        If Fun = 0 Or LookUp < Fun Then Fun = LookUp
    Next i

    Lowest = Fun
End Function

Private Function FindAverage(ByVal Criteria As Variant, _
                             Rng As Range) As Double
    ' 020

    Dim Fun As Double                   ' function return value
    Dim Arr As Variant                  ' table data range
    Dim Total As Double, n As Integer   ' calculate average
    Dim R As Long                       ' row counter

    ' truncate Criteria to the first 3 charcte4rs
    Criteria = Left(Criteria, 3)
    ' expand the range to include the 3rd column
    Arr = Rng.Resize(Rng.Rows.Count, 3).Value

    ' loop through all the cell values
    For R = 1 To UBound(Arr)
        ' compare the first 3 characters case insensive
        If InStr(1, Arr(R, 1), Criteria, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
            ' skip if there is no value in the 3rd column
            If Val(Arr(R, 3)) Then
                Total = Total + Arr(R, 3)
                n = n + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next R

    ' return zero if no qualifying values were found
    If n Then FindAverage = Total / n
End Function
```

Perhaps the first thing you need to learn is that code doesn't specify which worksheet to look at. That is because it's design as a UDF. It expects to take its instructions from the worksheet from which it is called. But the first procedure above, the one called `TestUdf` will **not** be called from a worksheet. You can use it for testing - after some adjustments.

The line `Debug.Print Lowest(Criteria, FirstTblID, NumTables)` will print something resembling your current formula's result to the Immediate Window. That's the pane across the bottom of your VB Editor screen. This function call has 3 arguments which you can set in the procedure, `Criteria`, `FirstTblID` and `NumTables`. The first is a cell containg the lookup value, like 2990001. The other two are there to show flexibility.

I named your 3 tables as `Table1`, `Table2` and `Table3`. Therefore the first table is #1 and the total number of tables is 3. The idea is that you might use the same function on tables 14 to 18. In that case `FirstTblID` would be 14 and `NumTables` would be 5. The function would return the lowest of 5 values.

In VBA all that is nicely spread out and explained with named variables to guide and comments to help. When you call the function from the worksheet there are no frills. In this case Cell(A20) is in the first column of your 4th table. The function would go into the 3rd column. From there it can be copied up and down like any other Excel function.

```
[C20] = Lowest(A20, 1, 3)
```

Now, the function returns the lowest of 3 values taken from the 3 tables (please remember to rename them!) but here comes the amendment you are asking about now. It's just a small change in the flow of the existing procedure. Here it is.

```
If Fnd Is Nothing Then
    ' if the Find wasn't successful
    LookUp = FindAverage(Crit, SearchRng)
Else
    LookUp = Fnd.Offset(0, 2).Value
End If
If Fun = 0 Or LookUp < Fun Then Fun = LookUp
```

Here you can see that VBA enables a completely different approach from the one worksheet functions support with reasonable effort. The above code decides for each of the three values individually. If one of them can't be found only that one value is replaced by an average of similar ones based on the first 3 digits. I know this isn't what you asked for but I thought you might not have dared ask. In VBA it's easy and, of course, it would just be a minor change to create the result you did ask for instead.

In my code the other way of calculating is contained in the separate function called `FindAverage`. The original function calls it only if needed but for purposes of maintenance it's a separate function that you might make available to other functions. In fact, you might call this function from the worksheet, too. The call would look as shown below but you would need to remove the `Private` from its declaration line so that it can been seen from the worksheet.

```
=FindAverage(A20,Table1[Ref-ID])
```

Following your suggestion, here is code to name the tables by their names. Observe that the function's name (here `Lowest2`) is repeated in the last line of code.

```
Function Lowest2(Criteria As Range, _
                 FirstTblID As Integer, _
                 NumTables As Integer) As Double
    ' 020 (with named tables)

    Dim Fun         As Double           ' function return value
    Dim Tbls()      As String           ' list of tables
    Dim Crit        As String           ' value of the received range "Criteria"
    Dim SearchRng   As Range            ' range to search in
    Dim Fnd         As Range            ' Cell where match was found
    Dim LookUp      As Double           ' individual lookup value
    Dim i           As Integer          ' loop counter

    Tbls = Split("Table1,Table2,Table3,Table4,Table5", ",")
    Crit = Criteria.Value
    For i = FirstTblID To (FirstTblID + NumTables - 1)
        Set SearchRng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(Trim(Tbls(i - 1))).DataBodyRange.Columns(1)
        Set Fnd = SearchRng.Find(What:=Crit, _
                                 After:=SearchRng.Cells(SearchRng.Cells.Count), _
                                 LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                 LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                 SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                 MatchCase:=False)
        If Fnd Is Nothing Then
            ' if the Find wasn't successful
            LookUp = FindAverage(Crit, SearchRng)
        Else
            LookUp = Fnd.Offset(0, 2).Value
        End If
        If Fun = 0 Or LookUp < Fun Then Fun = LookUp
    Next i

    Lowest2 = Fun
End Function
```

I have kept the function call identical to the original but added a line of code where you can specify the table names.

```
Tbls = Split("Table1,Table2,Table3,Table4,Table5", ",")
```

Whatever your table names might be, you list them here, comma-separated. You could specify `Split("Mary,Tom,Mary S,Thomas,Bangkok", ",")`.

Now the function call `Lowest2(A20,1,3)` specifies the first table from this list as `1` and the number of tables as `3`. That would mean that Table4 and Table4, both in the list, go unused. But you could also call `Lowest2(A20,1,5)` or, in fact, `Lowest2(A20,1,1)` to get a single value from one table. You could call `Lowest2(A20,3,3)` to get values from tables 3 to 5. You couldn't get values from tables 1, 3 and 5 but that would be only another minor change, too.

Comment: amazing explanation with details !! let me put that into action and get back to you. :) @variatus

Comment: you have made my life a whole lot easier :) , couple of questions - what if all the tables are named as "adam, jessica" etc instead of Table1,2,3 ? 2nd - the average for the bottom two ref-ID came out as 0.14476923. i couldnt figure out the result. vba is totally new to me and it seems its totally programming, so please pardon my questions and really appreciate your response and time. @variatus

Comment: On principle I prefer proper names over generic ones. If your tables have such names I shall amend my code. Please confirm that you want that. The code will find the first match (presuming there aren't more) of the search criterion in each table. Only if one isn't found the alternative average is inserted. In a controlled test you ought to be able to ascertain that the extraction/calculation is carried out correctly. Just look up the 3 values in the tables and see if the lowest one is returned.

Comment: To test the average, create a scenario in which the lookup value isn't available in only of the tables. It may help you to add either `Bebug.Print Lookup` or MsgBox Lookup` just above the line `If Fun = 0 Or LookUp < Fun Then Fun = LookUp`. Debug.Print will appear in the Immediate window at the bottom of the VB Editor window. The MsgBox will interrupt the macro until you click OK. In this way you get to see each of the 3 values being evaluated. Select A20 and press F2 (to enter edit mode) and Enter (to exit it) to cause the UDF to run once.

Comment: Thank you. I will follow your principle on names. For the last 2 refid, i would need to match the first three digits with next 3 table's [299] rows only and get an average or minimum. @variatus

Comment: I have added a variant to the original UDF which allows you to specify tables by name. Now, what to do if the search criterion isn't found lacks specification in the UDF context because it could not be found in one or all of the referenced tables. Your worksheet function doesn't make that distinction and neither does your question. How about moving that to a new thread?